# Simple deform modifier to sphere shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I read upon a previous post regarding the simple deform modifier.  But in this case I have made from honeycomb shapes a mesh, and have used 2 Simple deforms modifiers.
And I'd like to get it looking like a sphere. But the top and bottom doesnt look spherical, rather than squashed towards the poles. (South, north). I tried using the cast modifier, but made the sphere look awful. Any other way I can get this mesh looking round like a sphere?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't actually tessellate a sphere purely with hexagons](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065115/710477), the geometry doesn't work out.

However, a few (12) intrusions of pentagons make it possible. That makes a sort of expanded [Buckyball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene), or soccer ball. If that's acceptable, the only route I can find to it at the moment is to enable the shipped 'Tissue' add-on, create an Icosphere with enough subdivisions, and ask Tissue to '*Convert to Dual Mesh*' it.

[image]

I could have sworn you could get to this directly, at one time, using the 'Add Mesh: Extra Objects' add-on, but I can't find it in 2.81.. maybe someone knows?

Comment: Thanks for this tip Robert.

I got the result I was after within a minute add on + wire frame modifier. But I feel like I cheated the software and myself. I was mainly trying to achieve this result via a harder skill/technique so I can understand how an individual would do it manually, without the help of an add on. But because time is valuable to all of us, the result and new add on is more than welcomed.

Thank you.


https://ibb.co/23c0qL3

Comment: @blenderbreath Totally agree. I always feel you need to know stuff bottom up, otherwise, when the time comes, you don't know how to invent new ways for yourself. In this case, though, there's mathematically no way of deforming a hex grid into a perfect sphere.